# Getting null when concatenating string in linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

this is my query:

```
var db = new data.MQSDataContextDataContext();
string MonthY = divWave.InnerText.Substring(0, divWave.InnerText.IndexOf(","));
int waveN = Convert.ToInt32(divWave.InnerText.Substring(divWave.InnerText.IndexOf(",") + 1, 2));
int WorsheetID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
var wsItems = from wi in db.VendorOfferWorsheetItems
              where wi.WorksheetID == Convert.ToInt32(WorsheetID)
              select new resultsForGrid
              {
                  id = wi.id,
                  waveItemID = wi.waveItemID,
                  MName = wi.MName,
                  MQS_Code = wi.MQS_Code,
                  CustomerItemCode = wi.CustomerItemCode,
                  ItemDesc = wi.ItemDesc,
                  UOM = wi.UOM,
                  Ext = wi.Ext,
                  gCost = wi.gCost,
                  Vname = wi.Vname,
                  BestOffer = wi.BestOffer,
                  Margin = wi.Margin,
                  VendorOfferUOM = wi.VendorOfferUOM,
                  ItemWaveViewUrl = "../Waves/ViewWaveItemDetails.aspx?CurrentMonthYear=" + MonthY + "&CurrentWaveN=" + waveN.ToString() + "&Customer=" + divCustomer.InnerText + "&CustomerItemCode=" + wi.CustomerItemCode + "&UOM=" + wi.UOM + "&ItemNo=" + wi.MQS_Code
              };
```

t-sql (also returns null for ITemWaveViewUrl:

```
 SELECT ((((@p1 + [t0].[CustomerItemCode]) + @p2) + [t0].[UOM]) + @p3) + [t0].[MQS_Code] AS [ItemWaveViewUrl], [t0].[id], [t0].[waveItemID], [t0].[MName], [t0].[MQS_Code], [t0].[CustomerItemCode], [t0].[ItemDesc], [t0].[UOM], [t0].[Ext], [t0].[gCost], [t0].[Vname], [t0].[BestOffer], [t0].[Margin], [t0].[VendorOfferUOM]
    FROM [dbo].[VendorOfferWorsheetItems] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[WorksheetID] = @p0
```

why is ItemWaveViewUrl always returning null?

Comment: Are you sure that ItemWaveViewUrl is null? Is it possible that instead wsItems is null becuase there was no match on WorksheetID ?

Comment: I'm getting 3000 results with values except for ItemViewUrl

Comment: get rid of everything from the + onwards, check if the value is not null, add the next + variable, check if the value is not null, etc. Or use `String.Format("../url?cv={0}&sec={1} etc", wi.gCost, wi.Margin)`

Comment: string.Format will not translate to SQL I think. The string concatenation occurs in SQL, not LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LinqToSql if you concat a string with a null value you get `null`.

This is because the query is translated into a select using the [+ (String Concatenation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx):

> Just like arithmetic operations that are performed on null values,
>   when a null value is added to a known value the result is typically an
>   unknown value, a string concatenation operation that is performed with
>   a null value should also produce a null result.

You can fix this by transforming the result with LinqToObjects by using `AsEnumerable` on the query.

```
var worksheetId = Convert.ToInt32(WorsheetID);
var wsItems = db.VendorOfferWorsheetItems
    .Where(wi => wi.WorksheetID == worksheetId)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(wi => new resultsForGrid
            {
              id = wi.id,
              waveItemID = wi.waveItemID,
              MName = wi.MName,
              MQS_Code = wi.MQS_Code,
              CustomerItemCode = wi.CustomerItemCode,
              ItemDesc = wi.ItemDesc,
              UOM = wi.UOM,
              Ext = wi.Ext,
              gCost = wi.gCost,
              Vname = wi.Vname,
              BestOffer = wi.BestOffer,
              Margin = wi.Margin,
              VendorOfferUOM = wi.VendorOfferUOM,
              ItemWaveViewUrl = "../Waves/ViewWaveItemDetails.aspx?CurrentMonthYear=" + MonthY + "&CurrentWaveN=" + waveN.ToString() + "&Customer=" + divCustomer.InnerText + "&CustomerItemCode=" + wi.CustomerItemCode + "&UOM=" + wi.UOM + "&ItemNo=" + wi.MQS_Code
          });
```

Comment: From some quick googling, it seems the interwebs agree with you.  Still, a reference to some official documentation would make this an even better answer.

Comment: You are right, CustomerItemCode is null in all records.

Comment: LINQ2SQL only translates your coded intent to the SQL of the underlying database. This is why the second approach works, because wi is already an instance of a client type, thanks to AsEnumerable(). The only challenge here, if VendorOfferWorsheetItems has additional 100 columns, you'd be bringing them in as well, thus retrieving more data than you actually need.

Comment: @Darek Absolutely correct. This can be remedied by having an additional select before the `AsEnumerable` with only the relevant columns selected.